# jQuery toggle: Close all open li when another one is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an accordion menu which toggles on click. 
This is the code :

```
$('ul.internal-nav-list li ').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('.internal-sub-list li ').toggle();
});
```

And the markup looks like this:

```
<div id="internal-nav">
    <ul class="internal-nav-list"> 
        <li><a>products</a>
            <ul class="internal-sub-list">
                <li><a href="product1.aspx">product1</a></li>
                <li><a href="product2.aspx" >product2</a></li>
                <li><a href="product3.aspx">product3</a></li>                 
            </ul>    
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to enable that when an `li` element from the menu is open and the user clicks on another `li`, the open one will automatically close. Can anybody give me a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: How can the user click on another `li` if the rest are closed/hidden?

Comment: BTW you're missing a closing `</ul>` tag

Comment: they click on <li><a>products</> which toggles the li in the 'internal-sub-list' class. (Obviously there's more than one <li><a>...</a></li> but didn't want to post too much code)

Answer (score 0):

I'v I'm interpreting what you want correctly, try this:

```
var mainlis = $('.internal.nav.list > li'); // cache selector
mainlis.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var me = $(this);
  mainlis.hide();
  me.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to close all `li`elements and open only the one clicked

```
$('ul.internal-nav-list > li').on('click', function () {
  $(this).siblings('li').slideUp();
  $(this).slideDown();
});
```

**EDIT** As [Morfie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238389/morfie) pointed out, only the immediate children `li` of the `internal-nav-list` should be clickable, thus the `>` operator is used.

Comment: The problem is this targets even nested LIs.   You should alter this and use the '>' in your main jquery selector

Answer (score 0):

The other existing answers come close, but it seems like what you want to do is hide the children of other menu items when the main menu items are clicked. If that is the case, the following will do:

```
$('.internal-nav-list > li > a').on('click', function () {
  var $thisLi = $(this).parents('li');
  $thisLi.siblings().find('.internal-sub-list').hide();
  $thisLi.find('.internal-sub-list').show();
});
```

Note the first selector: this restricts the click handler to just the anchor, not the entire `li`. That means if they click on a child of the currently displayed main menu item, the function will not be called. That way you don't risk having a flicker as the click the submenu items...

In the handler itself, it traverses back to the parent `li`, finds its siblings and hides their children. Then is shows the submenu for the currently selected main menu.

Note that I took the liberty of hiding the entire `ul` of the non-selected menus; this should be faster than hiding each child. Perhaps not significantly, but I find it's best practice to perform these kinds of actions on the container rather than all children of the container.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions- I got it working this way in the end (in case it helps anyone)

```
 $('ul.internal-nav-list li').on('click', function () {
        $close = $(this).find('.internal-sub-list li ').toggle();
        $('.internal-sub-list li').not($close).hide()

    });
```